# Hello in Xamarin For Display Alert message I have used Acr.UserDialog .there is any soluction for change font size of title in case of uwp

Tags: xamarin

await UserDialogs.Instance.AlertAsync(new AlertConfig
            {

```
           Title="bhjgjh",
            Message = "hgfhg",
            OkText = "Ok" 
        });
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ! Please read : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.
It will give you some tips on how to format your questions.

Answer (score 1):

"The library wasn't really designed or meant for this. It was meant for using native dialogs. That's it. If you need something more customizable, this is not the library for it." - this text is copied from github repo "https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs".

So if you want to make your own custom dialog then try this 
https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup

or this
https://github.com/michaeled/FormsPopup